# Unable to change comments form using comment_form_default_fields hook

Tags: wordpress

Hi Im having trouble adding my custom fields to the default twentyten comment form. This is what im doing in the functions.php file of my child theme- am i forgetting something?

```
// Customise comment form for garage-sales page
if ( is_page('my-page') ):

add_filter('comment_form_default_fields','my_comment');
function my_comment($fields) {

    // New fields
    $fields['date'] = '<label>Date:</label><input type="text" name="date" value="'.(!empty($_POST['date']) ? $_POST['date'] : '').'" />';
    $fields['start_time'] = '<label>Start time:</label><input type="text" name="start_time" value="'.(!empty($_POST['start_date']) ? $_POST['start_date'] : '').'" />';
    $fields['end_time'] = '<label>End time:</label><input type="text" name="end_time" value="'.(!empty($_POST['start_date']) ? $_POST['start_date'] : '').'" />';
    $fields['early_birds'] = '<label>No early birds?:</label><input type="checkbox" name="early_birds" '.(isset($_POST['early_birds']) ? 'checked' : '').'  />';
    $fields['bad_weather'] = '<label>Bad weather?:</label><input type="checkbox" name="bad_weather" '.(isset($_POST['bad_weather']) ? 'checked' : '').' />';

    // Remove unwanted default fields
    unset($fields['url']);

    return $fields;
}
endif;
```

Comment: Your code looks good to me - my guess is that the conditional check for `is_page('my-page')` should be moved inside your filter function.

Comment: i just completely removed the conditional is_page() check,  so we can count that out from being an issue :/

Comment: Still no love? IMHO I think customizing the comments form in WP 3 is pretty poorly documented

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem where the filter 'comment_form_default_fields' is what displays on the comment form when you are not logged in.

The 'comment_form_field_comment' filter contains the code for when you are logged in.

Hope that made sense and helps

Comment: Thanks for the response Richard, I posted this one a while ago and havent been doing much work with WordPress lately so when I do get a chance I will check it out & accept your answer if it works ;)

Answer (score 0):

You have to point priority probably more than 10 like this

```
add_filter('comment_form_default_fields','my_comment',15);
```

It can be other filters on this hook in the parent theme or plugins which are invoked after your code.